# Output all rows with word count in a column greater than 3

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dummy df:

```
columns = ['answer', 'some_number']
data = [['hello how are you doing','1.0'],
       ['hello', '1.0'],
       ['bye bye bye bye', '0.0'],
        ['no', '0.0'],
        ['yes', '1.0'],
        ['Who let the dogs out', '0.0'],
        ['1 + 1 + 1 + 2', '1.0']]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, data=data)
```

I want to output the rows with a word count greater than 3.
Here that would the rows `'hello how are you doing', 'bye bye bye bye', 'Who let the dogs out', '1 + 1 + 1 + 2'`

My approach doesn't work: `df[len(df.answer) > 3]`

Output: `KeyError: True`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the seperator is `' '` ,you can try `series.str.count` , else you can replace the `sep`

```
n=3
df[df['answer'].str.count(' ').gt(n-1)]
```

To include Multiple spaces `#credits @piRSquared`

```
df['answer'].str.count('\s+').gt(2)
```

Or using list comprehension:

```
n= 3
df[[len(i.split())>n for i in df['answer']]] #should be faster than above
```

---

```
                    answer some_number
0  hello how are you doing         1.0
2          bye bye bye bye         0.0
5     Who let the dogs out         0.0
6            1 + 1 + 1 + 2         1.0
```

Comment: My vote goes to `count` as it doesn't waste resources creating lists.  However, to include possible multiple spaces: `df['answer'].str.count('\s+').gt(2)`

Answer (score 6):

If I understand this correctly, here's one way:

```
>>> df.loc[df['answer'].str.split().apply(len) > 3, 'answer']
0    hello how are you doing
2            bye bye bye bye
5       Who let the dogs out
6              1 + 1 + 1 + 2
```

Comment: @anky I just timed the oneliners. The `apply` version was a tiny bit faster. It's a matter of taste then I guess. I always find it a little weird to use the `.str` accessor on something that's not a string anymore.

Answer (score 6):

A couple more options using [`str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

- Combine with [`str.len()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html):

  ```
  df[df.answer.str.split().str.len().gt(n)]
  ```
- Or combine with [`apply(len)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

  ```
  df[df.answer.str.split().apply(len).gt(n)]
  ```

---

### What's fastest?

- Fastest overall ([BENY's list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66570668/13138364)):

  ```
  df[[x.count(' ') >= n for x in df.answer]]
  ```
- Fastest pandas-based ([anky's first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66570407/13138364)):

  ```
  df[df.answer.str.count(' ').ge(n)]
  ```

Timed with ~20 words per sentence:

[image: timing plot]

---

### Why doesn't `df[len(df.answer) > 3]` work?

`len(df.answer)` returns the length of the `answer` column itself (7), not the number of words per `answer` (5, 1, 4, 1, 1, 5, 7).

That means the final expression evaluates to `df[7 > 3]` or `df[True]`, which breaks because there is no column `True`:

```
>>> len(df.answer)
7

>>> len(df.answer) > 3     # 7 > 3
True

>>> df[len(df.answer) > 3] # df[True] doesn't exist
KeyError: True
```

Answer (score 4):

Try with count for string operation

```
n = 3
df[[x.count(' ') > n-1 for x in df.answer]]
Out[31]: 
                    answer some_number
0  hello how are you doing         1.0
2          bye bye bye bye         0.0
5     Who let the dogs out         0.0
6            1 + 1 + 1 + 2         1.0
```

Comment: Interesting thing about this compared to `pd.Series.str.count` is that Pandas will automatically use `re` to parse `'\s+'` in order to handle more than one space.  This solution requires using regex in some way.  Hmm, my brain is spending too much time on this question.